# Two xbee beacons drowning each other out?

Tags: arduino, xbee

I'm trying to create a pair of arduino/xbee beacons that will transmit some information (ultimately GPS coordinates) to each other at all times. The problem is that when they're both on, neither one seems to receive. I'm guessing it's because both might be transmitting at the same time and drowning the others message out. However, I'm not sure of a better approach since neither one is a slave or master. Here's my setup:

*Hardware:*

- A pair of [XBee-Pro 900 XSC S3B](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11634) xbees.
- A pair of teensy (arduino compatible with multiple UARTs)

*XBee Setup*

- VID: 542D
- DT: 8153
- Serial connected to Serial 3 on Teensy

*Code*

```
long lastTxTime = 0

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial3.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  long now = millis();

  // Send ever 0.5 seconds
  if (now - lastTxTime > 500) {
    Serial.println("SEND!");
    Serial3.println("WOOT!");
    lastTxTime = now;
  }

  delay(100);

  // Print anything received
  while(Serial3.available()) {
    char c = Serial3.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
}
```

When I connect both Teensy's to separate terminals, both of them output "SEND" and rarely receive a "WOOT". I put one of the XBees straight on a USB board to a terminal and it output most of the "WOOT" messages from the other.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Try removing the `delay(100);`.  It shouldn't be necessary since you only send once every 500ms and you only read and print from `Serial3` when there's data.  Another troubleshooting tip: remove the XBee modules and just connect directly connect the Teensy serial ports (Tx to Rx) and see if your code works.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look into is flow control. In the wireless standard, they use RTS (Request to Send) & CTS (Clear to Send). The RTS/CTS pins on Xbee might be what you need,

Comment: Cool. Does this mean that each of the xbees need to be in sync with who's sending and who's receiving? Or can I have each set RTS to HIGH when sending and CTR to HIGH otherwise? Or do they need to be more aware of the state of the other. The original design has two beacons, but in the future I would like to support many more.

Comment: The idea is to listen before you send and always be listening if you aren't sending. 

1) A send listens and checks for an idle channel.
2) It sends the request to send. 
3) Once the receiver gets that, it returns the clear to send on the channel.
4) The sender can then take the channel over with it's data. 
5) The receiver will not get onto the channel because if it tries to listen for idle, it will be getting data.

Look at the diagram for the idea. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance#mediaviewer/File:Csma_ca.svg

Comment: Forgot to answer your last questions. When doing a RTS/CTS scheme, all beacons will operate in this manner and all will be listening. Your data will have to include a packet header of some type. All stations will listen and check the header to see if the data it is for them.